# How to rename the word 'Tax' on ORDER SUMMARY to 'Estimated tax'?

Tags: tax

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
```

We need to rename the word Tax on ORDER SUMMARY from 'Tax' to 'Estimated Tax'. I was able to change the one below (which appears when you click the arrow) in `Stores --> Taxes --> Tax rules --> Tax Identifier = estimated tax` but not the one above.

[image]

I even tried:

```
Stores > Configuration > Developer > Translate Inline
```

But *it's not one of the words that can be changed via this process*.

---

UPDATED on September 12th, 2021:

I changed the following setting:

-> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Display Full Tax Summary = NO

and the front end changes where it takes out the 2nd line so it only looks like this:

[image]

**However I am still unable to edit the wording (*Tax to Estimated Tax*) using the Translate Inline option.**

---

---

UPDATED on September 13th, 2021:

**I figured out how to rename the word Tax on ORDER SUMMARY to Estimated tax** or anything else really:

**Change the following code in these 2 files:**

/

> vendor / magento / module-tax / view / frontend / layout /
> checkout_cart_index.xml

and

> / vendor / magento / module-tax / view / frontend / layout /
> checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/tax
</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="template"xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/tax
</item>
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated tax</item>
</item>
```

and

```
<item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/tax</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Estimated tax</item>
    </item>
    </item>
```

**Would anyone know how to change the word Tax to Estimated tax in Order Confirmation Emails?**

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause Analysis:**

My best guess is that the theme you're currently using does NOT use the translate function ( `__()`) for that specific Label.

**Solutions:**

I see you've mentioned Amasty in the question/post, so I assume you're using an Amasty Theme. If so - You could ask Amasty for a Patch to address that issue.

(In my experience, they'll usually give you a patch within 48 hours)

*OR*

You could modify that by changing the Content, of that specific template file, in your Theme.

(I do NOT recommend this, as it will get blow away during an upgrade)

*OR*

You can create another Custom-Theme - that extends your Amasty theme - and in your Custom theme overwrite the appropriate Template File(s) to use the Translate function.

(This is probably your fastest, and safest, way to solve the issue)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. We do not have an Amasty theme though. Our theme is the #1 most used Magento theme in the world = Smartwave Porto theme. I don't think we will be doing any upgrades to be honest so your 2nd recommendation might just work! Would you happen to know which path/file to modify? And what modification to make? Thank you.

Comment: I've gone to Smartwave Porto (the providers of our theme) and they have come back with the following: "Checkout and the elements in the checkout page are the core functionality of Magento default, How this function works is the behaviour of the Magento default, not Theme related."

Comment: Regarding the 2nd suggestion (to modify that by changing the Content, of that specific template file, in our Theme) - would you know how I can do that?

Comment: And I honestly have no idea how to implement your 3rd suggestion = create another Custom-Theme - that extends our PORTO theme - and in our Custom theme overwrite the appropriate Template File(s) to use the Translate function?